# Links to information on IOSurfaces and IOMobileFramebuffer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-privateapi

I have been working on iOS to experiment with creating a screen recorder using private/public API's. I have come across IOSurfaces and IOMobileFramebuffer and have used them. Apple has not documented these frameworks since they are private(There is part documentation by apple on IOSurfaces in Mac).I am interested in reading more on these topics and understanding them in details. So, if anyone could provide good links to any documentation on these topics and related methods/functionalities would really be helpful.

Thanks.